Are the following definitions for $SO^*(2n)$ all equivalent?
I found three different definitions of the Lie group $SO^*(2n)$
1/ In the book Representation Theory of Semi-Simple Lie Groups  of Prof. Knapp (Princeton Landmarks in Mathematics Edition), cap 1.1 page 6, it is said that it is a matrix subgroup of $SU(n, n)$ such that
$$g^t\pmatrix{0&\mathbb{I}_n\\\mathbb{I}_n&0}g=\pmatrix{0&\mathbb{I}_n\\\mathbb{I}_n&0}$$
2/ In the book Introduction to Arithmetic Groups of Witte-Morris Appendix A it is said that is a matrix subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{H})$ such that
$$\tau(g^t).g=\mathbb{I}_{2n}$$
where $\tau$ is the reversion defined on $\mathbb{H}$ by $z_1+j z_2\to z_1- j\ \overline{z_2}$
3/ In the following MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223622/reference-on-representation-theory-of-so2n, it is said that it is a matrix subgroup of $SO(2n, \mathbb{C})$ such that
$$
M^\dagger\eta \,M=\eta,\qquad \eta =
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\mathbb{I}_n \\
-\mathbb{I}_n &0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
which means for orthogonal complex matrices that they belong to $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$
I have some trouble finding them equivalent, especially with the 1/ definition. I guess I have to prove that the defining matrices in 1/ and 3/ are similar. Can somebody help me?

Actually I found the right matrix to do the similarity. If we set
$$s=\frac1{\sqrt{2i}}\begin{pmatrix}
1&-i \\
i&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
we get
$$s^t.s=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1 \\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$s.\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1 \\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}.s^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix}
-i&0 \\
0&i
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then if $g$ is a matrix of dimension 2 verifying definition 1/, then $s^{-1}.g.s$ verifies condition 3/.
It is then easy to show the definitions are actually equivalent.
